# Parsing between fields

Tags: perl, awk, sed

```
    {
        “docheck”: {
            “mycheck”: “apples”,
            "result": [macintosh
                       washington
                       red]
    },
```

Am looking for an awk command to print the outcome as:

```
    apples: macintosh
                washington
                red
```

Unsure how to parse this (NR, FNR) and would appreciate any assistance or if awk is even the best solution for this. Semi solution:

```
$ more file
{
    “docheck”: {
        “mycheck”: “apples”,
        "result": [macintosh
           washington
           red]
    },
```

**UPDATE** (semi solution but there is likely a better way

```
$ more file
{
    “docheck”: {
        “mycheck”: “apples”,
        "result": [macintosh
           washington
           red]
    },

$ awk '/mycheck/{flag=1;next}/}/{flag=0}flag' file |\
sed 's#:##g;s#\[##g;s#\]##g;s#"##g' | perl -p -e 's:\n:,:g;s:\t::g' |\
awk '{print $1":"$2,$3,$4}'
```

result:macintosh, washington, red,

Comment: why the perl and sed tags if you want awk?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Could you convince the source to use JSON or something structured? The data you gave looks nearly JSON...

Comment: The data is coming from an API query using curl to terminal

Comment: @GerhardBarnard am looking to see if it can be done with awk or sed solely, this is the part I can't figure out.

Comment: Are there really no quotes around the items in the `result` array? Which API is this?

Comment: Did your data at some point pass a Word document or Outlook? The quotes look totally off.

Answer (score -1):

with sed :

```
sed -n '/^.*mycheck”: “/{s//\t/;s/”,/:/;N;s/\n[^[]*\[/ /;N;N;s/]$//p}' infile
```